# Как запретить удалять нужные файлы, но разрешить создавать/изменять/удалять прочие файлы?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

Допустим, есть такая файловая система ext4 с точкой монтирования /ILYA, в которой находится файловое хранилище, и как пример, абсолютный путь к одному из файлов.

```
/ILYA/Music/W.A.S.P/1984 - W.A.S.P/01 - I wanna be somebody.flac
```

Возникла необходимость сделать так, чтобы никто кроме меня, знающего пароль root-а, не мог удалять существующие файлы, но при этом мог создавать/править/удалять свои, причём даже в тех директориях, где присутствуют мои.

1. Попробовал просто заменить владельца этих файлов `root`-ом.

   ```
   p='/ILYA' && sudo chown -R root:root "$p" && sudo chmod -R =r,u+w,+X "$p" && chown user "$p"
   ```

   Но, оказывается, пользователь `user` без проблем удаляет любой файл, принадлежащий пользователю `root`, если он владелец родительской директории `/ILYA`, а в директории `/ILYA/Music` он уже не может удалять, но и не может создавать. Вариант не сработал.
2. Добавил stickybit.

   ```
   p='/ILYA' && sudo chown -R root:root "$p" && sudo chmod -R =r,u+w,+X,+t "$p" && chown user "$p"
   ```

Но это вообще ничего не изменило.

Подскажите, как решить эту задачу, или что я недосмотрел, или, хотя бы, куда мне копать?

**Ответ.**

Основная моя ошибка была в том, что я считал атрибуты `chmod` `=r,u+w,+X,+t` и `a=trX,u+w` эквивалентными на основании того, что `=r` было эквивалентно `a=r`. Запись с `a=` и короче, и красивее, и понятнее, а главное выполняет то, что от неё требуется. (Сбросить все привилегии и заново установить для всех пользователей стикибит, чтение, и если это директория, то и выполнение, а для владельца, по мимо этого, ещё установить запись)

И так моя задаче решается такой командой, к сожалению, без `find` не обойтись.

```
p='/ILYA' && sudo chown -R root:users "$p" && sudo chmod -R go-w "$p" && sudo find "$p" -type d -exec chmod a+t,g+w "{}" \;
```

Вернуть назад.

```
p='/ILYA' && sudo chown -R user:users "$p" && sudo chmod -R a-t,g-w "$p"
```

А также, в случае, если нужно запретить удалять **даже root-у**, тогда нужно использовать `chattr` + `find` только на файлы, пропуская директории.

```
p='/ILYA' && sudo find "$p" -type f -exec chattr +i "{}" \;
```

В этом случае эти файлы, причём уже совершенно не важно кто ими владеет, не сможет удалить **даже root**, пока `root` не снимет атрибут `i`, j, обратной командой.

```
p='/ILYA' && sudo find "$p" -type f -exec chattr -i "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

выдержка из `man chattr`:

> A  file  with the `i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

вольный перевод:

> файл с атрибутом `i` не может быть модифицирован: он не может быть удалён или переименован, на него невозможно создать «жёсткую» ссылку (*hardlink*) и в него невозможно записать информацию. только суперпользователь или процесс, обладающий «возможностью» (*capability*) `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` может установить или удалить этот атрибут.

пример. создадим от имени рядового пользователя файл:

```
$ touch file
```

он принадлежит «рядовому» пользователю:

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jul 29 20:42 file
```

и не имеет (пока) никаких спецатрибутов:

```
$ lsattr file
---------------- file
```

установим атрибут `i`:

```
$ sudo chattr +i file
$ lsattr file
----i----------- file
```

попробуем удалить:

```
$ rm file
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `file'? y
rm: cannot remove `file': Operation not permitted
```

даже суперпользователь этого не сможет сделать:

```
$ sudo rm file
rm: cannot remove `file': Operation not permitted
```

пока не снимем атрибут `i`:

```
$ sudo chattr -i file
```

теперь и «рядовой» владелец сможет его удалить:

```
$ rm file
```

---

можно установить этот атрибут и на каталог. тогда **всё содержимое** каталога (но не подкаталогов, у которых атрибут **не** установлен) станет (частично) неизменяемым: нельзя будет создавать/удалять/переименовывать файлы/каталоги, но можно будет изменять содержимое файлов.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. :-)
Никогда не сталкивался с chattr и acl, но видимо придётся. :-)
Проблема теперь в том, что при рекурсивном вызове он накладывается и на директории, что в свою очередь препятствует созданию в них файлов.
Можно ли стандартными средствами chattr как-то применить рекурсивно только для файлов, не затрагивая директории, например, как флаг X в chmod?

Comment: 1. это **не** *acl*. 2. `$ sudo find каталог -type f -exec chattr +i {} \;`

Comment: Почитал маны на chattr это что-то такое... даже не знаю сказать что.
Кроме атрибутов "i" и "u", там ничего полезного и нет. На счёт атрибута "u" заранее никогда не знаешь, какой файл случайно удалишь, так что польза от "u", скажем так, специфическая.
Но и главная фишка chattr, атрибут "i", как я понял, предназначен именно для того, что бы запретить удалять даже root-у. Не спорю, в некоторых случаях это очень даже нужно и полезно, но не в моём случае.

Comment: Поэкспериментировал с find + chmod и обнаружил, что указания прав БЕЗ буквы (=r) Ведёт себя не так, как я ожидал. Отсутствие буквы отнюдь не равно a, хотя "=r" эквивалентно "a=r", но "=rwx" даёт вот такой, неожиданный для меня, результат. "-rwxr-xr-x". Теперь буду везде использовать букву "a", например `sudo chown -R a=rX,u+w`.

А свою задачу, я решил используя stickybit вот так.
`p='/ILYA' && sudo chown -R root:users "$p" && sudo chmod -R a=rX,u+w "$p" && sudo find "$p" -type d -exec chown root {} \; && p='/ILYA' && sudo find "$p" -type d -exec chmod a=trx,ug+w {} \;`

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объединить `sudo find "$p" -type d -exec chown root {} \; && sudo find "$p" -type d -exec chmod a=trx,ug+w {} \;` в одну команду?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: Ну я считаю, это будет довольно мелкий вопрос в рамках отдельного вопроса. Это скорее дополняющий к этому, если это, конечно возможно вообще сделать.
Там, скорее всего или так `... -exec chown root {} && chmod a=trx,ug+w {} \;` или так `... -exec chown root {} \ && chmod a=trx,ug+w {} \;`

Хотя вы в любом случае, ответили на мой основной вопрос, точнее навели меня на него, что мне и требовалось. :-)
Спасибо вам. :-)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550065/209154

Answer (score -2):

попробуй изменить права для файлов `chmod 700 *`

Comment: Если оставить владельца ilya, то это не даст ничего, если root, то файлы перестанут быть доступны на чтение всем кроме root-а, а мне нужно что бы они были доступны на чтение всем.