# Как в утилите find с атрибутом exec выполнить несколько операций с файлом

Tags: linux, unix

Есть команда, состоящая из 2-ух частей, одинаковых циклов поиска, но с разными действиями для найденных файлов.

```
sudo find '/tmp' -type d -exec chown root "{}" \; && sudo find '/tmp' -type d -exec chmod a=trx,ug+w "{}" \;
```

Возможно ли её объединить, и если да, то как?

P.S. `... -exec chown root "{}" && chmod a=trx,ug+w "{}" \;` не помогает, выводит:
`find: missing argument to -exec'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно указать `-exec` несколько раз:

```
find '/tmp' -type d -exec chown root {} \;  -exec chmod a=trx,ug+w {} \;
```